# Navigation menu margin

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS / HTML and I have a problem with creating a nav.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #232323;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e24a4a;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>M1</li>
    <li>M2</li>
    <li>M3</li>
    <li>M4</li>
    <li>M5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Between M's is margin. I don't want it. I tried remove them, but nothing.

Margin between M's

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: You set padding on the `li` elements

Comment: the  padding: 15px 20px; line is causing it

Comment: That's not an actual `margin`. Go read https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: It's not margin. It is padding. when you say `padding: x x` then it means padding for `padding: (top and bottom) (left and right)`

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something this.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

li {
  padding: 15px 0;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

li:hover {
  padding: 15px 20px;

  background-color: #232323;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e24a4a;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>M1</li>
    <li>M2</li>
    <li>M3</li>
    <li>M4</li>
    <li>M5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the details given in the link that CBroe posted... Will provide you with the solutions. In my opinion both the "flexbox" and the "negative margin" solutions are pretty good tricks.

Here you go:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-right: -4px; /* negative margin */
  height: 35px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #232323;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e24a4a;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>M1</li>
    <li>M2</li>
    <li>M3</li>
    <li>M4</li>
    <li>M5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```